# Disable all input elements in a div, and enable them one-by-one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML code. I am using Jasny bootstrap for image upload, and Bootstrap-Switch do get the iOS style switch box.

By default, I want to:

1. Disable every element in Div #one except the very first switch box. (It is in the indeterminate state to start with)
2. When the user flicks that first element to either on or off, the next input field becomes enabled.
3. And so on.

Basically, I want the user to have to fill out the form in order.

Not all of the fields are check boxes. As you can see from this example, there is an image upload form which I want to work in the same way - disabled until the field before it has been completed, and then enabled. And once the image has been uploaded, then enable the next input field, and so on.

Is there any jQuery magic I can use to easily do this?

```
    <div id="one">
    <!-- Bootstrap switch box -->
    <div class="s-part-question">
        <label>X</label>
        <div>
            <input name="X1" type="checkbox" class="s-switch-indeterminate s-t-input"
                   data-indeterminate="true"
                   data-on-text="Yes"
                   data-off-text="No" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap switch box -->
    <div class="s-part-question">
        <label>Y</label>
        <div>
            <input name="Y1" type="checkbox" class="s-switch-indeterminate s-t-input"
                   data-indeterminate="true"
                   data-on-text="Yes"
                   data-off-text="No" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Image upload -->
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new s-part-photo" data-provides="fileinput">
        <div class="s-part-photo-explain">Add image</div>
        <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
        <div>
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                <span class="fileinput-new">New</span>
                <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                <input class="s-t-input" type="file" name="imageY1">
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap switch box -->   
    <div class="s-part-question">
        <label>Z1</label>
        <div>
            <input name="Z1" type="checkbox" class="s-switch-indeterminate s-t-input"
                   data-indeterminate="true"
                   data-on-text="Yes"
                   data-off-text="No" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

     $(".s-switch-indeterminate").bootstrapSwitch({
         'state': null
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but the way I did it was to dynamically include the HTML after every section. So I would start in the HTML with:

```
<div id="one">
  <div id="first">
    <!-- Bootstrap switch box -->
    <div class="s-part-question">
      <label>X</label>
      <div>
        <input name="X1" type="checkbox" class="s-switch-indeterminate s-t-input"
               data-indeterminate="true"
               data-on-text="Yes"
               data-off-text="No" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
  <div id="fourth"></div>
  etc.
```

where I've added a div section for each checkbox with its own unique ID (first, second, third etc).

Then when the checkbox has changed, you can check it with jQuery and insert the next sections HTML with Javascript.

```
$("input[name='X1']").change(function() {
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML =  '<div class="s-part-question"><label>Y</label><div><input name="Y1" type="checkbox" class="s-switch-indeterminate s-t-input" data-indeterminate="true" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" /></div></div>'
}
```

Then have one of these for each checkbox. Also note for the dynamically generated checkbox, you will have to have to make a change to the jQuery selector to so:

```
$('#one').on("input[name='Y1']", "change", function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the following:

(1) Every DIV element is disabled, except the first one.
(2) When the user checks the checkbox in the first DIV on or off (to checked or not checked), then the second checkbox becomes enabled. This second checkbox stays enabled even when the user change the first checkbox back to what it was.
(3) Then when the second checkbox is checked (or unchecked if already checked), the next input becomes enabled.
(4) And so on...

If so, the next codes should help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div#one > div");//Selects all DIRECT child elements specified by “child” of elements specified by “parent”. In this case it takes the parent DIV of the switch boxes and all its children (and inner html) "only one level down".
    //http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
    var amountInputs = new Array();
    for(i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++){
        //In each Bootstrap switch box 
        var inputFields = nodeList[i].querySelectorAll("input");
        amountInputs[i] = inputFields.length;
        if( i==0 ){
            putOnSurveillance(inputFields);
        } else{
            for(j=0;j<amountInputs[i];j++){
                $( inputFields[j] ).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }
    }
    jObjects['amountInputs'] = amountInputs;
});

var jObjects = { /* JavaScipt Objects */ 
    current_SwitchBox: 0,//Current switch box index number
    surveillancePassed: 0
};

function enableNextSwitchBox(){
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div#one > div");
    if( jObjects['current_SwitchBox']!=nodeList.length ){
        var inputFields = nodeList[jObjects['current_SwitchBox']].querySelectorAll("input");
        for(l=0;l<inputFields.length;l++)
            $( inputFields[l] ).prop("disabled", false);
        putOnSurveillance(inputFields);
    } else{
        //No more Switch Boxes to enable!!!
    }
}

function putOnSurveillance(inputs){
    for(k=0;k<inputs.length;k++){
        $( inputs[k] ).change( {targetInput: inputs[k]}, function(object) {
            $( object.data.targetInput ).unbind('change');//You are not under "surveillance" anymore...
            if( jObjects['amountInputs'][jObjects['current_SwitchBox']]==(++jObjects['surveillancePassed']) ){
                ++jObjects['current_SwitchBox'];
                jObjects['surveillancePassed'] = 0;
                enableNextSwitchBox();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1)Variable " nodeList " is the DIV which contains all the Bootstrap switch boxes
2)Variable " nodeList[] " -> in each nodeList[i] (i-> 0,1,2,3....) contains a Bootstrap switch box
3)Next: at each nodeList[i], we will searches for any input tags (or elements). If there is more than one input fields in that switch box, it will automatically detect them.
4)Disable all input fields, but the input fields in the "FIRST" Bootstrap switch box.
!This only works with "input" tags!
5)An amount of `<input>` per Bootstrap switch box will be saved as JavaScript Object for use later
6)The `<input>`'s of the first Switch Box (which are not disabled), are put on "surveillance". If its value is changed, that same input won't be on "surveillance" anymore, and then by using a javascript object (variable), it will check if all other `<input>`'s in that same Switch Box has already changed before.
If so, then all `<input>`'s on the next Bootstrap Switch Box becomes enabled.
7)The `<input>`'s on the next switch box are enabled and so on....

Bonus: This code should work with any type of input + any amount of input you have in that particular Bootstrap switch box + any amount of Bootstrap switch boxes you have!!!